# if statement targets undefined parameter in locally stored JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, local-storage, undefined

So this script is supposed to validate log in info sent as a GET method in the URL, create a string from it, append it to a URL to get JSON from the server, then store the JSON in localStorage. That all works fine.

Then it's supposed to assess the user's status based on certain parameters (was the login info correct? if so, are they an admin?) That's where it breaks down.

Everything comes out as "invalidated" because  "myObjDeserialized.valid" is coming back as "UNDEFINED", and i'm not sure why, since the JSON is showing:
[accountid: 1234
admin: 1
userID: "guard"
**valid: "true"**]

here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>

    window.onload = function()
    { 
        ///////////////
        // Part 1.
        ///////////////

        //gets parameters   
        var getParameters = window.location.search.substring(1);

        //appends parameters to  desired URL.
        var fullURL = 'http://hh.offsitevision.com:26000/httpHandHeldService.aspx?' + getParameters;

        alert('fullURL is: ' + fullURL);


        ///////////////
        // Part 2.
        /////////////// 
        function readTextFile(file, callback) 
        {
            var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
            rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") 
                {
                    callback(rawFile.responseText);
                }
            }
            rawFile.send(null);
        }


        // apply the "fullURL" from before to the call to return data. 
        readTextFile(fullURL, function(text){

            var data = JSON.parse(text);
            //console.log(data); 


                    ///////////////
                    // Part 3.
                    /////////////// 
                    //sets data for the object.
                    //var myObj = myJSON;


                    //turns the object into a string.
                    var myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(data);

                    //Stores the object in localStorage.
                    localStorage.setItem("data", myObj_serialized);



                    ///////////////
                    // Part 4.
                    /////////////// 
                    //Gets the object out of storage (and converts it back form a string to an object). 
                    var myObjDeserialized = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));

                    console.log(myObjDeserialized);

                    //Checks data in local object and assess it, then displays appropriate code.    



                    ///////////////
                    // Part 5.
                    /////////////// 
                    var userStatus = "";

                    alert('deserialized!  ' + myObjDeserialized.valid)

                    if (myObjDeserialized.valid == true) 
                    { 
                        alert("User is validated."); 
                        userStatus = "User is Validated. "

                        if (myObjDeserialized.admin == 1) 
                        { 
                                alert("User is an Admin. " ); 
                                userStatus = userStatus + "<br>And the User is an Admin. "
                        } 
                        else{
                                alert("User is not Validated.");
                                userStatus = userStatus + "<br>but they are NOT an admin."
                        }
                    } 
                    else{
                        alert("User is not Validated.");

                        userStatus = "The login information you provided is not correct."
                        }


                    ///////////////
                    // Part 6.
                    /////////////// 
                    //Write the assesment information to <p ID="writeFromLocalStorage"></p>
                    document.getElementById("writeFromLocalStorage").innerHTML += userStatus;


        });







    }

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>hello world.</h1> 
<p ID="writeFromLocalStorage"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Part 1. get params and write them to a URL to get json. 
Part 2. get External JSON
Part 3. write the json returned from that URL in LocalStorage. 
Part 4. get the json out of storage.
Part 5. assess the users status. 
Part 6. write the users status to the markup.

Seems like something in either Part 4 or 5 is broken, which is causing the variables in the if statements to come back undefined.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

UGHHHHHH.  Of course as soon as  post it I realize what I did.

the "=="'s in the if statements shoudl be "="'s

Never mind.